# Vue event bus with templates and separate components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

The web app I'm building has two different states. I want to have a button in one of the states that switches to the other and modifies some of it's children (through refs) by way of an event bus. The problem is, I can't figure out how to "wait" for the refs to be initialized after the event is received.

Registering the event handler in mounted doesn't work because it will still listen to events after the component is unmounted. I want to receive an event, switch states, wait until the refs have been rendered (ideally with a lifecycle hook or something) and then do something to the refs.

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/92710/

js

```
const EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.component('compa', {
    mounted: function(){
    //this is the part that is broken
    EventBus.$on('swap-to-a', () => console.log(this.$refs))
  },
  template: `<p ref = "reference">in state a</p>`
})

Vue.component('compb', {
  methods: {
    emit: () => {EventBus.$emit('swap-to-a')}
  },
  template: `<button v-on:click = "emit">swap to a</button>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    mounted: function(){
    EventBus.$on('swap-to-a', () => this.mode = "a");
  },
  data: {
    mode: "b"
  }
})
```

html

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click = "mode ='b'">
  swap to b  
  </button>
  <template v-if = "mode=='a'">
    <compa></compa>
  </template>
  <template v-if = "mode=='b'">
    <compb></compb>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to do something with compa, why don't you use `created` hook of compa. Don't need to use EventBus.

Comment: in the real application, compa is receiving data from compb, so the event bus in necessary.